# How do I translate Field Group labels?

Tags: 8

I have two field sets

[image: Fieldsets]

In the admin/config/regional/translate I have translated the "Account settings" label
[image: accountsettingstranslation]

But in the Form display I still have the english label:
[image: formdisplay]
What can I do to translate the field group labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-05/2546212-119.patch - Did the trick for me.
It adds a "Translate form display" tab, like it is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Field groups are configurations which are not translated via the translation interface. I am quite sure that the string "Account settings" that is translated in your project does not come from your field group. Just change the label of a field group to any other string - you will not find the string in the translation interface.

You need to activate the "Configuration Translation" module.

Comment: Yes, this is configuration, but unfortunately the UI to translate formatter/widgets is not ready yet. See https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group/issues/3114825

Comment: Yes, indeed @4k4 , I found the same issues and so far I cannot find the string to translate it. One patch I found https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-07-10/allow_html_in_field_group_label.patch and applied it to the module, lets me output it as HTML, could this be resolved somewhere as a translation?

Comment: You need to install the core modul mentioned in the answer and then patch this module with https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2546212#comment-13451232. After that your field group formatter/widget configuration should look like the screenshot you see in the issue I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort of work around this with theming. In my situation I am unable to use the patch so this is what I did. I created a theme suggestion that includes my "bundle" and "group name" so I can override the fieldset.html.twig templates for the specific field groups I want to translate.

In my themes .theme file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_fieldset_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $group_name = $element['#group_name'];
  $bundle = $element['#bundle'];
  if (!empty($group_name) && !empty($bundle)) {
  $suggestions[] = 'fieldset__' . strtr($bundle, '-', '_') . '__' . strtr($group_name, '-', '_');
  }
}
```

Now I can add a template for each of my content types field groups using `fieldset--CONTENT-TYPE--GROUP-NAME.html.twig`.

At this point I can copy the `fieldset.html.twig` code into my template and replace the legend with a translatable string.

```
<legend{{ legend.attributes }}>
  <span{{ legend_span.attributes.addClass(legend_span_classes) }}>{{ 'Translatable Text Using User Interface Translation'|trans }}</span>
</legend>
```

Make sure you visit your page in the language you want to translate before searching for your string in the User Interface Translation UI. It won't find your string until you do.

Bam! Easy, narrowly scoped work around until field groups gets the patch into a release.